# Exception not supported using npgsql and mono

Tags: c#, postgresql, mono, npgsql

I am currently trying to use a Windows Service with mono. The problem is that i have an exception when I create a NpgsqlConnection object (so before using the Open method).

`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

That line is always followed by this one :

`Keyword not supported: user#012Parameter name: keyword`

I am using postgres 13.2 and npgsql 4.0.0.
I am using the constructor that way :

```
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=flexipark_monitor;User=postgres;Password=postgres;");
```

Thanks.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show how you create the object and what parameters you are using.

Comment: I am using the constructor that way : NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=flexipark_monitor;User=postgres;Password=postgres;");

Answer (score 0):

I have not said it but I was loading my parameters from a file and putting them directly in the code works. It's probably an encoding problem. So the question is answered.

Comment: Please do not put additional information pertinent to the question in an answer. Instead update the question with the additional information.